# Flexicious DatagridColumns columnWidthMode='percent' not showing correct

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flexicious

I'am using a Flexicious Datagrid for showing some basic information. This datagrid has a width and height of 100% based on the parent container (a HGROUP).

When I apply a `columnWidthMode="percent"` mode to all of the `DatagridColumns` where all the `percentWidth` properties add up to a 100%, the last `DatagridColumn` is much bigger than all the other columns, and for some reason this triggers a horizontal scrollbar. I have a feeling that the DataGrid does not respect the 100% width, but makes it much bigger.

Is there some special property I'm missing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem above.

Because the Flexicous DataGrid had the property `HorizontalScrollPolicy` set to `auto` the columns didn't resize as expected. By removing this property (by not setting it to a specific value) the horizontal scrollbar wasn't visible anymore, with a result that the columns scaled correctly!